# The existential theory is undecidable

Tags: number-theory, logic, computability, formal-languages

**Lemma 1.**

> For any $x$ in the ring $F[t,t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$), $x$ is a power of $t$ if and only if $x$ divides $1$ and $t-1$ divides $x-1$ (the divisibilities are meant, of course, in $F[t, t^{-1}]$).

**Lemma 2.**

> Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Then for any $n$ in the ring $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$), $n$ is a nonzero integer if and only if $n$ divides $1$ and either $n-1$ divides $1$ or $n+1$ divides $1$, and there is a power $x$ of $t$, so that $(x-1)/(t-1)
>  \equiv n \pmod {t-1}$.

**THEOREM.**

Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ is undecidable.

*PROOF.*

By Lemma 1, we can express the fact that an element $x$ in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is a power of $t$ by an existential formula $\phi(x)$.

By this and Lemma 2, we can express the fact that an element $n$ of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is an integer by the existential formula $$(\exists x)(\exists y) [\phi (x) \wedge x-1 = (t-1)n+y(t-1)^2] \wedge (\exists z)(\exists w) (nz =1 \wedge  ((n+1)w=1 \text{ or } (n-1)w=1)$$ 
Call the last formula $\psi(n)$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction, that the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is decidable.

Then we can algorithmically examine the solvability of a diophantine equation in the rational integers in the following way:

if $P(X_1, \dots , X_n)=0$ is a given diophantine equation, we consider the existential formula $$(\exists x_1) \dots (\exists x_n) P(x_1, \dots , x_n)=0 \wedge \psi(x_1) \wedge \dots \psi(x_n)$$

Clearly, the equation of whether this sentence is true in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is equivalent to the question of whether $P=0$ has integral solutions. 
But this contradicts the negative answer to Hilbert's Tenth Problem; therefore, the theorem follows.

$$$$

---

Could you explain to me the formula $\psi(n)$ ?

Could you explain to me the reduction to Hilbert's Tenth Probelm? I haven't really understood it...

$$$$

---

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Can we change the theorem and its proof as follows?

**THEOREM.**

We suppose that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Then the **positive** existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ is undecidable.

*Proof.* 
We want to show that there is no algorithm, that given a **positive** existential sentence $\gamma$, it answers if $\gamma$ is true in the ring $F[t, t^{-1}$ or not. 
According to Matijasevic, there is no algorithm that with input a polynomial $P(x_1, \dots , x_n)$ with integer coefficients, always decides if the equation $P(X-1, \dots , x_n)=0$ has an integer solution. 
According to Lemma $1$, an element $x \in F[t, t^{-1}]$ is a power of $t$ iff $$x \mid 1 \ \ \land \ \ t-1 \mid x-1$$ 
So we can express the fact that an element $x \in F[t, t^{-1}]$ is a power of $t$ with the **positive** existential formula $$\phi (x) \ \ : \ \  \exists y \exists z ((xy=1) \land (x-1=(t-1)z))$$ 
According to Lemma $3$, $n$ is a nonzero integer iff

- $n \mid 1 \ \ : \ \ (\exists z)(nz=1)$
- $n-1 \mid 1 \lor n+1 \mid 1 \ \ : \ \ (\exists w)((n+1)w=1 \text{ or } (n-1)w=1)$
- there is a power $x$ of $t$ $\ \ : \ \ (\exists x) \phi (x)$
- $(x-1)/(t-1) \equiv n \pmod {t-1} \ \ : \ \ (\exists y)((x-1)/(t-1)-n =y(t-1)) \Rightarrow (\exists y)(x-1-n(t-1)=y(t-1)^2) \Rightarrow (\exists y)(x-1=n(t-1)+y(t-1)^2)$

So we can express the fact that an element $n \in F[t, t^{-1}]$ is an integer with the **positive** existential formula $$\psi (n) \ \ : \ \ (\exists x)(\exists y)[\phi(x) \land x-1=(t-1)n+y(t-1)^2] \land (\exists z)(\exists w)(nz=1 \land ((n+1)w=1 \text{ or } (n-1)w=1)$$ 
We suppose that the **positive** existential formula of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is decidable, so there is an algorithm that decides if a **positive** existential sentence is true in $F[t, t^{-1}]$. 
Then the problem if a diophantine equation has an integer solution is decidable: 
the diphantine equation $P(x_1, \dots , x_n)=0$ has an integer solution iff the **positive** existential sentence $$(\exists x_1) \dots (\exists x_n) ((\psi (x_1) \land \dots \land \psi (x_n)) \land P(x_1, \dots , x_n)=0)$$ is true in $F[t, t^{-1}]$. 
But the answer to the $10^{th}$ Hilbert's Problem, i.e., if there is an algorithm that decides if the diophantine equation has an integer solution, is negative. 
So we have a contradiction. 
That means that the **positive** existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

Comment: Because of my background, this stuff is easy for me, a standard reduction to Hilbert's 10th.  I had noticed it but have no time for a while. Am bookmarking, and if no one else has given a full answer by the time I get to it, I will write out an answer.

Comment: Ok!! @AndréNicolas

Comment: it would be helpful if you cite ref, pg

Comment: It is from this paper: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275396?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents @vzn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We explain the reduction, and later, if questions arise, explain $\psi$.

A formula $\alpha(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k)$ is *existential* if it has the shape 
$$\exists t_1\exists t_2\cdots \exists t_l\beta(x_1,\dots,x_k, t_1,\dots,t_l),\tag{1}$$
where the formula $\beta(x_1,\dots,x_k, t_1,\dots,t_l)$ is *quantifier-free*.  Sometimes, informally, as in the definition you quote for $\psi(n)$, the term *existential formula*  is used for formulas that can be mechanically put in the form (1). (Note that as given, the existential quantifiers are not all in front.)

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$. We want to show that there is **no algorithm** which, given **any** existential sentence $\gamma$, will tell us whether or not $\gamma$ is true in the ring $F[t,t^{-1}]$.

By the result that culminated in the work of Matijasevic, there is no algorithm which, when given as input a polynomial $P(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ with integer coefficients, will always determine whether or not the equation $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ has a solution in integers.

We show that **if there were** an algorithm for determining the truth in $F[t,t^{-1}]$ of existential sentences, then there would be an algorithm for determining the solvability of Diophantine equations in the integers. But there is no such algorithm.

The reduction strategy is in principle simple. Given any Diophantine equation $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$, we show how to **construct** explicitly an existential sentence $\alpha_P$ such that $\alpha_P$ is true in $F[t,t^{-1}]$ if and only if $P(X_1,\cdots,X_n)=0$ has a solution in integers. Now suppose we had an algorithm to determine the truth of existential sentences in $F[t,t^{-1}]$. Then by applying the algorithm to $\gamma_P$, we could determine whether or not the Diophantine equation $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ has a solution, contradicting the (negative) solution of Hilbert's $10$-th Problem.

By Lemmas 1 and 2, there is an existential  formula $\psi(w)$ such that $w\in F[t,t^{-1}]$ satisfies the formula $\psi$ if and only if $w$ is an ordinary integer.  Thus $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ has an integer solution if and only if the sentence
$$\exists x_1\cdots,\exists x_n((\psi(x_1)\land\dots\land \psi(x_n))\land P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0)\tag{2}$$
is true in $F[t,t^{1}]$. In the sentence (2), the existential quantification ranges over $F[t,t^{-1}]$. The subformulas $\psi(x_i)$ informally say "$x_i$ is an ordinary integer."

Note that the subformulas $\psi(x_i)$ are existential, involving $4$ existential quantifiers each. We need to use $4n$ distinct existentially quantified variables for the $\psi(x_i)$, and we need to bring them to the front in (2) so that the resulting sentence will be genuinely existential.

That's all there is to the reduction. Suppose further that $-1$ is never a sum of squares in the field $F$. This is true in particular if $F$ is a subfield of the reals. Then by a trick you are by now familiar with, we say a little more. Given any polynomial $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ with integer coefficients, we can construct a polynomial $P^\ast(x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)$ with integer coefficients such that the Diophantine equation $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ has a solution in the integers if and only if the equation $P^\ast(x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m)=0$ has a solution in $F[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: I understand now the reduction!! But I still do not understand the definition of the formula $\psi(w)$... Why does $\psi(w)$ imply that $w$ is an ordinary integer? $$$$ Could you explain to me the last patragraph? I have not understood how we use the fact that $-1$ is never a sum of squares in $F$.

Comment: I will (perhaps tomorrow, busy time, long term visitors), deal with $\psi$, it is the subject of another of your questions. The stuff about $-1$ was really not relevant to your main question, about existential definability, it was just a side comment. When we write (i) $P_1(\bar{u})=0)\land P_2(\bar{v})=0$ (with existential quantifiers in front) we have an existential formula. If the sum of squares is $0$ iff each term is $0$ (true in the rationals, the reals, but not the complexes) we can replace the $\land$ by $P_1^2+P_2^2=0$, which makes it look more Diophantine.

Comment: By the way, the big open problem in this game, that people have been working on for more than 40 years, is whether there is an algorithm for determining solvability of Diophantine equations in *rationals*.

Comment: I imagine you are gathering a bibiliography on the subject. An active person has been Bjorn Poonen.

Comment: I should also mention Alexandra Shlapentokh (my spelling may be off).

Comment: What is your fundamental issue with $\psi$?  Is it (i) the algebraic lemmas that precede it, which lead to the fact that the ordinary integers are the polynomials in $F[t,t^{-1}]$ that have certain special algebraic properties, or is it (ii) the expression of these properties into a specific existential formula?

Comment: The existential formula $\psi(n)$ means that $n \in F[t, t^{-1}]$ is an integer. 
$$$$ 
By Lemma $2$, we have that $n$ is a nonzero integer iff $n$ divides $1$ and either $n-1$ divides $1$ or $n+1$ divides $1$, and there is a power $x$ of $t$, so that $(x-1)/(t-1) \equiv n \pmod {t-1}$.

Comment: So, the formula has the following properties: 
$$$$
-$n$ divides $1$ : $(\exists z) nz=1$ 
$$$$
-either $n-1$ divides $1$ or $n+1$ divides $1$ : $(\exists w) ((n+1)w=1 \text{ or } (n-1)w=1)$ 
$$$$
-there is a power $x$ of $t$ : $(\exists x) \phi(x)$ 
$$$$
-$(x-1)/(t-1) \equiv n \pmod {t-1}$ : By this property we get $(\exists y) (x-1=(t-1)n+y(t-1)^2)$, right? Why? At this property I got stuck... How did we get $x-1=(t-1)n+y(t-1)^2$ ?

Comment: Division is not an allowed operation in the language of rings. To describe the congruence condition, we want to say that $(x-1)/(t-1)-n$ is divisible by $t-1$, which means there is a $y$ such that $(x-1)/(t-1)-n=y(t-1)$, which means (multiply through  by $t-1$) that there is a $y$ such that $x-1-n(t-1)=y(t-1)^2$, or equivalently $x-1=n(t-1)+y(t-1)^2$.

Comment: I understand... Thanks for the clarification!! :-) 
$$$$ 
You said that a formula $\alpha (x_1, x_2, \dots , x_k)$ is existential if it has the shape $$\exists t_1 \exists t_2 \dots \exists t_l \beta (x_1, \dots , x_k, t_1, \dots , t_l)$$ where the formula $\beta (x_1, \dots , x_k, t_1, \dots , t_l)$ is quantifier-free. 
$$$$ 
When is the formula positive existential? When $\beta(x_1, \dots , x_k, t_1, \dots , t_l)$ is quantifier-free and contains only equations and not inequations?

Comment: For existential positive, existential quantifiers (or none) in front, no logical connectives other than $\land$ and/or $\lor$  inside.

Comment: So, at a **positive** existential formula there are no logical connectives other than $\land$ and/or $\lor$ inside. At an existential formula are there also other logical connectives other the above ones? Or which is the difference?

Comment: In an existential formula negation (and implication) are allowed inside. For stuff connected with Hilbert's 10th problem, the distinction is usually not important, since one can replace $\lnot(P=Q)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are terms, by a negation-free existential formula, as in the four squares trick.

Comment: Could you give me an example of an existential formula and an example of a positive existential formula?

Comment: At once existential and positive existential $\exists s\exists t (w=(s\cdot s)+(t\cdot t))$.  Existential but not positive existential: $\exists s\exists t((w=(t\cdot t)) \lor \lnot(w=s\cdot t))$. (Not proofread for parentheses, comments are difficult that way.)  Note that the set of positive existential formulas is a proper subset of the set of existential formulas.

Comment: Ok... I see... Thank you very much for your help!! :-)

Comment: You are welcome. May your further endeavours along these lines go well!

Comment: I am reading again the proof and I have a question to make sure if the following is correct... Is the existential formula $\phi (x)$ the following? $$\phi (x): \exists y \exists z((x y=1) \land (x-1=(t-1)z))$$

Comment: I will not be able to answer for quite a few hours, entertaining, family have priority.

Comment: I have edited my initial post... I changed a little the theorem and the proof, to show that the **positive** existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable. Could you take a look at it if we can change the "existential theory" to "positive existential theory" ?

Comment: Or is there an other way to justify that the **positive** existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable?

Comment: I will think about it. But the reduction to Hilbert's 10th problem via positive existential sentences seems like the natural way.

Comment: So the way I formulated the proof is correct, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, the expression you wrote down is positive existential, as is the rest.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-) $$$$ Could you suggest a book that contains definitions, like the definition of a language, of an (positive) existential formula, etc?

Comment: Language is defined in every logic book. As to positive existential formula, your paper may have been the first use. However, *positive formula* has been around a long time, many model theory books mention it.  Sorry about not being more specific, I am away from books, hope to be away from the university for another week at least.

Comment: While I was reading some proofs I got stuck about the reduction.I thought again about it.Is it as followed?We want to show that the (positive)existential theory $T$ is undecidable and we know that (positive)existential theory $T$ is undecidable.We prove the undecidability of $T$ by reducing $T'$ to $T$,i.e.,by translating the set of $T'$ into the (positive)existential theory of $T$.We can suppose that $T$ is decidable,then we conclude that $T'$ is also decidable,and so we get a contradiction.Or we can say that since $T'$ is undecidable we cocnlude that $T$ is also undecidable.Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. One way to prove that there is no algorithm fr settling the truth of existential sentences of $T$, or positive existential sentences, is to find a theory $T'$, usually ordinary number theory, and an **algorithm** that given any existential sentence $\varphi$ of $T'$, produces an existential (or positive existential) sentence $\psi$ of $T$ such that $\varphi$ is true in $T'$ if and only if $\psi$ is true in $T'$. In principle there might be other ways to do it, but that is the way all such results have  been obtained so far, as corollaries of the Matijasevich result.

Comment: Indeed the Matijasevich result was in a sense obtained in a similar way, as a consequence of the Julia Robinson result on undecidability of exponential diophantine equations.  And this result was obtained by encoding bounded universal quantification, so ultimately derives from the basic Goedel result. The logic of the argument is always simple. If there were an algorithm for settling problem B, there would be one for problem A, but it is known that there isn't.  Of course the details of the reductions are sometimes difficult.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) Could you take a look at my formulation of the proof of the theorem of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382120/ft-has-undecidable-positive-existential-theory-in-the-language-cdot and tell me if I have understood correctly the idea of the reduction?

Comment: I will try, but I am not really an algebraist.  I scanned the reply of Arthan, and it seemed to cover much of the ground. I will be more comfortable when you finally get to DE, where I once knew a few things.