# Algorithm to answer existential questions - Reduction

Tags: number-theory, logic, computability, formal-languages, proof-explanation

**Lemma 1.**

> For any $x$ in the ring $F[t,t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$), $x$ is a power of $t$ if and only if $x$ divides $1$ and $t-1$ divides $x-1$ (the divisibilities are meant, of course, in $F[t, t^{-1}]$).

**Lemma 2.**

> $t^n-1$ divides $t^m-1$ in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$) if and only if $n$ divides $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Lemma 3.**

> Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is $p$ and $p>2$. 
>   Then $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$) if and only if $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}) m=np^s$.

**THEOREM.**

Assume that $F$ has characteristic $p>2$. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

*PROOF.*

We think of the powers of $t$ as representing the integers; thus, $t^n$ represents the integer $n$. By Lemma $1$, the set of powers of $t$ is existentially definable.

Addition of integers $m+n$ corresponds to multiplication of the corresponding powers of $t$, $t^mt^n$.

By Lemma $2$, the relation "$n$ divides $m$" (where $n$ and $m$ are given through their corresponding powers $t^n$ and $t^m$) is existentially definable.

Moreover, the relation $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=p^sn$, by Lemma $3$, is also existentially definable.

Therefore, if we had an algorithm to answer existential questions over $F[t, t^{-1}]$, we could convert it to an algorithm to answer existential questions in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the structure of addition, divisibility, and the relation $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=p^sn$.

In an other paper it is shown that the last structure has undecidable positive existential theory (more accurately, one can define multiplication in a positive existential way in it, and therefore, the complexity of its positive existential theory is the same as the complexity of the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ with addition and multiplication).

It follows that the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

$$$$

---

How exactly do we conclude from the lemmas to the following? I haven't really understood it... Could you explain it to me?

Therefore, if we had an algorithm to answer existential questions over $F[t, t^{-1}]$, we could convert it to an algorithm to answer existential questions in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the structure of addition, divisibility, and the relation $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=p^sn$.

$$$$

**EDIT1 :**

The language is $\{+,\cdot , 0,1,t\}$.

I read again the proof and I undetstood the following:

We suppose that the existential theory of $F[t,t^{-1}]$ is decidable, that means that there is an algorithm that answers existential questions over $F[t,t^{-1}]$.

We want to reduce it to the existential theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the structure of addition, divisibility, and the relation $(\exists s\in\mathbb{Z})m=p^sn$, which is undecidable.

To do so, we do the following:

One part of the "translation" of the reduction is the mapping $t^n\mapsto n$.

So, the set "powers of t" corresponds to "integers".

So, we have to be able to "filter out" the powers of $t$ from all the other elements of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ in an existential way, according to Lemma $1$, permitted by the language.

We have that $t^mt^n=t^{m+n}\mapsto m+n$ so $\mathbb{Z}$ has the structure of addition.

By Lemma $2$ , $\mathbb{Z}$ has the structure of divisibility.

And by Lemma $3$, $\mathbb{Z}$ has the structure of the relation $(\exists s\in \mathbb{Z})m=np^s$.

Is that the idea of reduction? Have I understood it correctly?

$$$$

**EDIT2:**

I am reading again the proof and I got stuck at the following point:

We say that by Lemma $2$, $\mathbb{Z}$ has the structure of divisibility.

Do we conclude to that because this lemma can be written as an existential formula which is true in $F[t,t^{-1}]$ ?

But the language does not consist of the divisibility. How is this existential formula?

$$$$

**EDIT3:**

Why doesn't the theorem stand also for $p=2$ ?

Comment: If you are asking about a published paper, it would be helpful to have a citation to it.  It seems that you have quoted a bunch of "results", only to ask how those lead to some conclusion about "existential questions in $\mathbb{Z}$."

Comment: I agree with hardmath: please give the citation if you are quoting from a published paper. In any case, to answer your question we need to know what language you are using to talk about $F[t, t^{-1}]$. If you have quoted Lemma 1 correctly, it looks to me as if $t$ is intended to be represented by a constant in the language.

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it?$$$$  It is from this paper: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275396?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Shall I upload a picture of the paper of the part that is related to the above?

Comment: You do not know from Lemma 1 that *each* element is a power of $t$. What you do know from Lemma 1 is that you can characterize the subset of those element in an existential way. And, this is sufficient.

Comment: I edited my post above... Could you tell me if it correct now? @quid

Comment: It is still not quite what you write. Lemma 1 gives you a method to describe the subset of powers of $t$. Informally, I would describe it as: Lemma 1 tells us how we can distinguish the powers of $t$ from any other element. The point is: as you say correctly the set "powers of $t$" corresponds to "integers" However to use this effectively you need to be able to "filter out" the powers of $t$ from all the other elements in a way permitted by your language. Therefore you cannot just say it is a power of $t$, but need  Lemma 1 to know that you can describe them.

Comment: I edited again my post above... Could you tell me if it is correct now? @quid

Comment: It is informal but otherwise fine, I think.

Comment: How could we say it more formal? @quid

Comment: I have also an other question... I found the theorems http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375844/the-existential-theory-is-undecidable and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380768/algorithm-to-answer-existential-questions-reduction at a paper of Pheidas. I have heard that Denef proves also these theorems but I don't know exactly at which paper... Do you maybe know the paper of Denef? @quid

Comment: You might say what you said on the other question: "By Lemma 1, we can express the fact that an element $x$ in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is a power of $t$ by an existential formula $\phi(x)$." Sorry I do not know these papers.

Comment: Why doesn't the theorem stand also for $p=2$ ? @quid

Comment: Moemntarily I do not know. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

I have had a chance to look at the paper now. Your description of the reduction and your understanding of the argument is perfectly correct. Your restatement of Lemma 1 is not quite right as explained by quid in acomment above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The only question being asked in the OP's posting is whether her understanding is correct. I have answered that question.My answer is not a  critique or a request for clarification.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza So that you know, there is currently [a discussion on the meta about this review](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21141/how-do-you-answer-is-my-understanding-correct).

Comment: @RobArthan much ado about nothing

Comment: Why doesn't the theorem stand also for $p=2$ ?

Comment: Annoyingly, Pheidas doesn't number the theorems. The theorem you've quoted is the one stated after lemma 5, Its proof uses lemma 5 which requires $p > 2$ so Pheidas has only given the proof for $p > 2$. The remark following the theorem says that the theorem also holds for $p = 2$ but the proof needs a modification to lemma 5.

Comment: So at lemma 5 do we need to find an other property that must be hold when $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ is a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ? Or an other property that must be hold when $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=n2^s$ ?

Comment: If $\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $m=2^s n$, then $2 \mid m$ and $n \mid m$. 

We have the following: 

$$2 \mid m \Leftrightarrow t^2-1 \mid t^m-1$$ 

and $$n \mid m \Leftrightarrow t^n-1 \mid t^m-1$$ 

Is this an "iff" statement? @RobArthan