# Why doesn't this hold for $p=2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, positive-characteristic

I have a question about the following lemma:

> Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is $p$ and $p>2$. 
>   Then $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ if and only if $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}) m=np^s$.

($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$)

We assume that the characteristic of $F$ is $p>2$. Why can the characteristic not be $p=2$. Is it because then we would have $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}=a^2=1$ ?

Can we modify a little the lemma so that it stands for characteristic $p=2$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT1:**

Can we say something about $p=2$ ?

$$(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=2^sn \Leftrightarrow \dots$$

If $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=2^sn$ then we have that:
$$t^m=t^{2^sn}=\left (t^n\right )^{2^s} \Rightarrow t^m-1=\left (t^n\right )^{2^s}-1=\left (t^n-1\right )^{2^s}$$

Can we write with that a $\Leftrightarrow$ relation?

$$$$

**EDIT2:**

Using te lemma:

> $t^n-1$ divides $t^m-1$ in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$) if and only if $n$ divides $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

we have the following:

If $\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $m=2^s n$, then $2 \mid m$ and $n \mid m$.

We have the following:

$$2 \mid m \Leftrightarrow t^2-1 \mid t^m-1$$

and $$n \mid m \Leftrightarrow t^n-1 \mid t^m-1$$

Is this an "iff" statement?

Comment: Who deleted my comment?

Comment: I don't know... All the comments are deleted... How can that be? Maybe a moderator deleted them ? But why? @principal-ideal-domain

Comment: If you didn't do it, could it be a bug?

Comment: I didn't do that... I really don't know what it is... @principal-ideal-domain

Comment: Do you maybe know if there is a similar lemma that stands for $p=2$ ? @principal-ideal-domain

Comment: I am not sure to understand the EDIT. The equivalence $t^m = (t^n)^{2^s} \iff t^m-1 = (t^n)^{2^s}-1$ is trivial, isn't it ? So what is the question?

Comment: When we have the relation $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})m=n2^s$ what can we say about the elemets of $F[t, t^{-1}]$, do they satisfy then a property? @J.-E.Pin

Comment: But you wrote yourself that if $m = n2^s$, then $t^m - 1 = (t^n -1)^{2^s}$. Isn't it an answer to your question?

Comment: Is this also a 'iff' statement? @J.-E.Pin

Comment: I am asking this, because I am looking at this theorem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380768/algorithm-to-answer-existential-questions-reduction and I am wondering if we can change something so that the theorem stands also for $p=2$. @J.-E.Pin

Comment: Please do not change questions after they have been answered. If you have an additional question, think it through, formulate it well, and ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 8):

If $F$ is the $2$-element field, one has $\frac{t^2-1}{t-1}=t + 1$, but $1+t$ is not a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$.

Comment: If the characterisitc is $p=2$ we have that if $\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m=2^sn$, $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}=\frac{t^{2^sn}-1}{t^n-1}=\frac{(t^n-1)^{2^s}}{t^n-1}=(t^n-1)^{2^sn-1}$ right? And that is not a square. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. In other words for $n = 1$, $m = 2$ and $s=1$ you get a counterexample in characteristic $2$.

Comment: Can we modify a little the lemma so that it stands for characteristic $p=2$ ?

Comment: This is a different question and I didn't think about it. I suppose you want to find our for which values of $(m,n)$ the term $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$, right?

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: I edited again my initial post... Could you take a look at it? Is this correct? Is this an "iff" statement?