# Show undecidability by reducing from Hilbert's $10^{th}$ problem

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, formal-languages

To show that the existential theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the language $\{0, 1; +, \mid , \mid_p\}$ (where $x \mid_p y \Leftrightarrow \exists r \in \mathbb{N} : y=\pm xp^r$) is undecidable we have to reduce Hilbert's tenth problem to this one, i.e., we have to reduce the existential theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the language $\{0, 1; +, \cdot \}$ to the existential theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the language $\{0, 1; +, \mid , \mid_p\}$.

Is this correct?

To do that do we have to express for example the formula $a=b \cdot c$ with the language $\{0, 1; +, \mid , \mid_p\}$ ?

We have that $$a=b \cdot c \Leftrightarrow a=\frac{(b+c)^2-(b-c)^2}{4}$$

So we have to express the formula $d=e^2$ in terms of the language $\{0, 1; +, \mid , \mid_p\}$.

Is this correct so far?

I suppose that to express $d=e^2$ we have to use $\mid_p$. I have done the following:

$$d=e^2 \tag 1$$

$$d=d_1p^l \ \ \text{ such that } d_1 \nmid p \ \ , \ \  e=e_1p^r \ \ \text{ such that } e_1 \nmid p$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow d_1p^l=e_1^2(p^r)^2=e_1^2p^{2r} \Rightarrow d_1=e_1^2p^{2r-l}$$ $$d_1 \mid e_1^2 \Rightarrow e_1^2=\lambda d_1, \lambda \in \mathbb{Z} \\  e_1 \mid d_1 \Rightarrow d_1=ke_1 , k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow e_1^2=\lambda k e_1 \Rightarrow e_1=\lambda k$$ We would have to conclude that $d_1=e_1$ so that we can conclude that $d=ep^{l-r}$, right? But how? Or is my idea wrong?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Or can we maybe just say $$d=e^2 \Leftrightarrow d \mid e =e$$ ?

Comment: Is your $|_p$ a three-place relation, or a countable family of two-place relation symbols? Is the $p$ required to be prime?

Comment: It is "correct so far" that you have described how your problem can be reduced to that of expressing $d=e^2$ in your target language. I can't say for certain whether that reduction actually constitutes progress, though.

Comment: $\mid_p$ is a two-place relation. $p$ is a prime. @HenningMakholm

Comment: I suppose that to express $d=e^2$ we have to use $\mid_p$. I have done the following: $$d=e^2 \tag 1$$ 
$$d=d_1p^l \ \ \text{ such that } d_1\nmid p \ \ ,\ \  e=e_1p^r \ \ \text{ such that } e_1\nmid p$$ 
$$(1)\Rightarrow d_1p^l=e_1^2(p^r)^2=e_1^2p^{2r}\Rightarrow d_1=e_1^2p^{2r-l}$$ $$d_1 \mid e_1^2\Rightarrow e_1^2=\lambda d_1,\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}\\  e_1\mid d_1\Rightarrow d_1=ke_1,k\in \mathbb{Z}$$ $$\Rightarrow e_1^2=\lambda k e_1\Rightarrow e_1=\lambda k$$ We would have to conclude that $d_1=e_1$ so that we can conclude that $d=ep^{l-r}$,right?But how?Or is my idea wrong? @HenningMakholm

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning there, but the conclusion appears to be false. For example, $p=3$, $d=36$, $e=6$ gives $d_1=4$ and $e_1=2$, which are not equal. (In general, I doubt one could use the $|_p$s to construct a general-purpose squaring predicate, because any formula you could end up with can mention only finitely many of them).

Comment: Can we maybe just say $$d=e^2 \Leftrightarrow (d \mid e =e)$$ ? @HenningMakholm

Comment: I don't think "$d\mid e=e$" is well-formed. "$d\mid e$" is a _formula_ and so is "$e=e$"; neither can appear as a parameter to the other predicate.

Comment: The existence of the reductions you describe is sufficient but not necessary (so each time you write "we have to" what you should say is "it is sufficient to"). There could be a completely different approach to the proof. I agree with Henning that your approach to the algebraic problem is not correct. What you are trying to prove is the result cited in the paper by Pheidas you asked about in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380768/algorithm-to-answer-existential-questions-reduction/1385515#comment2917957_1385515. Pheidas's reference [De4] should give the proof.