# $F[t]$ has undecidable positive existential theory in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$

Tags: number-theory, logic, computability, formal-languages

Consider the ring $F[t, t^{-1}]$ (the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$).

**Theorem 1.**

> Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ is unecidable.

**Theorem 2.**

> Assume that $F$ has characteristic $p>2$. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

We have that even the positive existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

Now we give a Lemma that, together with the preceding results, allows us to conclude the undecidability of the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$.

**Lemma.**

> If the characteristic of $F$ is other than $2$, then the solutions of $$X^2-(t^2-1)Y^2=1$$ with $X$ and $Y$ in $F[t]$ are given by $$(X, Y)=(\pm x_n, y_n)$$ where $$x_n+\sqrt{t^2-1}y_n=(t+\sqrt{t^2-1})^n$$ fr $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Theorem 3.**

> If the characteristic of $F$ is other than $2$, then $F[t]$ has undecidable positive existential theory in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$.

*Proof.*

Write $u=t+\sqrt{t^2-1}$.

Then $u^{-1}=t-\sqrt{t^2-1}$ and $F[u, u^{-1}]=F[t, \sqrt{t^2-1}]$.

We interpret the positive existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in $F[t]$ in the following way:

an element $x$ of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is represented as a pair $x=(a, b)$ with $a, b$ in $F[t]$ being the components of $x$ with repsect to the base $\{u, u^{-1}\}$ considering $F[u, u^{-1}]$ as a module over $F[t]$; addition and multiplication of elements of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is defined accordingly.

So, we see that the positive existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is interpretable in $F[t]$ with only one problem: we do not have constants for $u$ and $u^{-1}$ but only for $\frac{u+u^{-1}}{2}=t$.

So, the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ is undecidable provided that the theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable in the language $\{0, 1, u+u^{-1}/2, +, \cdot\}$.

It is only a matter of routine checking to see that our undecidability result for $F[u, u^{-1}]$ holds true in this language as well: simply substitute $v=u-t$, write all equations involved in the form $fv=g$, where $f$ and $g$ have coefficients in $F[t]$ (the quantity $v^2$, wherever it appears, is replaced by $t^2-1$ which is in $F[t]$) and substitute the equations of this last form by the corresponding equations $f^2(t^2-1)=g^2$.

Of course, it is necessary to check that the new solutions that come onto the scene through the squaring do not do any harm to the stated equivalences.

Hence, the theorem follows.

---

$$$$

How do we use the Lemma at the proof of Theorem $3$ ? How is it useful?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

That's how I understood the whole proof of Theorem $3$ :

We know that the existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, u\}$ is undecidable.

We want to reduce the positive existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, u\}$ to the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ to show that this theory is also undecidable.

To do that we do the following:

We suppose that the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ is decidable.

We set $u=t+\sqrt{t^2-1}$. So, we have that $u^{-1}=t-\sqrt{t^2-1}$.

So, we have $F[u, u^{-1}]=F[t, \sqrt{t^2-1}]$. So, $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is an extension of $F[t]$.

Each element $x$ of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written as followed: $x=a+b\sqrt{t^2-1}$, where $a,b \in F[t]$.

So, the mapping of the reduction is $x \mapsto (a,b)$.

$+ \ \ : \ \  $ $$x_1+x_2=a_1+b_1\sqrt{t^2-1}+a_2+b_2\sqrt{t^2-1}=(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\sqrt{t^2-1} \mapsto (a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2)$$
$\cdot  \ \ : \ \  $ $$x_1\cdot x_2=(a_1+b_1\sqrt{t^2-1})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{t^2-1})=a_1 \cdot a_2+a_1 \cdot b_2 \sqrt{t^2-1}+a_2 \cdot b_1\sqrt{t^2-1}+b_1 \cdot b_2 (t^2-1)=(a_1 \cdot a_2+b_1 \cdot b_2 (t^2-1))+(a_1 \cdot b_2+a_2 \cdot b_1)\sqrt{t^2-1} \mapsto (a_1 \cdot a_2+b_1 \cdot b_2 (t^2-1), a_1 \cdot b_2+a_2 \cdot b_1)$$ 
$0  \ \ : \ \  $ $$0=0+0 \sqrt{t^2-1} \mapsto (0,0)$$ 
$1 \ \  :  \ \ $ $$1=1+0 \sqrt{t^2-1} \mapsto (1,0)$$
$u \ \ : \ \  $ $u \mapsto u-t=:v$. We write all the equations in the form $fv=g$ where $f,g \in F[t]$ and squaring these equations we get $f^2v^2=g^2 \Rightarrow f^2(t^2-1)=g^2$, so all these equations are in $F[t]$, where $t=(u+u^{-1})/2$.

So we can convert the algorithm that answers to positive existential questions of $F[t]$ to an algorithm that answers to existential questions of $F[u, u^{-1}]$.

Since the second theory is undecidable, we get aa contradiction. So the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ is undecidable.

$$$$

Is this correct?

Comment: to me none of this make any sense

Comment: As explained in another post by the OP http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380768/algorithm-to-answer-existential-questions-reduction/1385515#1385515  she is trying to understand a paper by Pheidas on Extensions of Hilbert's tenth problem http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275396?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @mercio: PS: you can definitely be forgiven for not being aware of the context as the OP didn't choose to tell us.

Answer (score 7):

You are, I believe, asking about a proof in the paper [Extensions of Hilbert's Tenth Problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275396?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Thanases Phaedas. You've asked three questions about this. The background is that Phaedas has proved that the existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable (he actually wrote $t$ rather than $u$ when he proved, but he has now switched to $u$). He is trying to get stronger result by reducing decidability in the polynomial ring $F[t]$ to decidability in the ring of Laurent polynomials $F[u, u^{-1}]$. The approach is to extend $F[t]$ to $F[t, s\mathrel{|} s^2 = t^2 - 1]$ (but Phaedas doesn't quite put it like that). Then one observes that $F[t, s]$ is isomorphic to $F[u, u^{-1}]$ under an isomorphism that associates $t$ with $(u + u^{-1})/2$ and $s$ with $(u - u^{-1})/2$.

Your first question is:

> > an element $x$ of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is represented as a pair $x=(a, b)$ with $a, b$ in $F[t]$ being the components of $x$ with repsect to the base $\{u, u^{-1}\}$ considering $F[u, u^{-1}]$ as a module over $F[t]$
>
> Does this mean that we write any element $x$ of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in the form $x=au+bu^{-1}$ ?

It means that every $x \in F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written uniquely as $x = au+bu^{-1}$ for $a, b \in F[t]$. However, I believe this is false. $F[t, s]$ is a free module of rank $2$ over $F[t]$, a suitable base being $\{1, s\}$ (which Pheidas would write as $\{1, \sqrt{t^2 - 1}\}$). What this means is that every element $x \in F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written uniquely in the form $a + bs$ with $a, b \in $F[t]$.  I believe this is just a (very significant) typo.

Your second question is:

> We have that each element of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be represented as an element of $F[t]$, besides $u$ and $u^{-1}$, becasuse the language does not consist of a square root. Is this correct?

What we have is that each element of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be represented uniquely as a pair of elements $a, b$ of $F[t]$ with $(a, b)$ representing $a + bs$ (following my correction to Pheidas's statement about the basis above).

Your final question is:

> > $\ldots$ simply substitute $v=u-t$, write all equations involved in the form $fv=g$, where $f$ and $g$ have coefficients in $F[t]$ (the quantity $v^2$, wherever it appears, is replaced by $t^2-1$ which is in $F[t]$) $\ldots$
>
> Why can we write all the equations in the form $fv=g$, where $f$ and $g$ have coefficients in $F[t]$ ?

$F[u, u^{-1}]$ is generated over $F$ as a ring by $t$ and $v$, hence any equation in $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written as $p(t, v) = 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$, but $v^2 = t^2-1$, so we can arrange for $p$ to have the form $vf(t) - g(t)$ for $f, g \in F[t]$. and then $p(r, t) = 0$ is equivalent to $fv = g$.

Comment: You say that the approach of the reduction is to extend $F[t]$ to $F[t,s\mid s^2=t^2-1]$ and at the beginning of the proof we take $u=t+\sqrt{t^2-1}$. Why do we take this extension? Which the reason that we take this $u$ ? $$$$ What does it mean that "$F[t,s]$ is a free module of rank $2$ over $F[t]$" ?

Comment: I have tried to expand my answer a bit to help with these comments. To say a bit more out the motivation: if you play around with the elements $t = (u + u^(-1})/2$ and $s = (u + u^{-1})/2$ in the ring of Laurent polynomial $F[u, u^{-1}]$, you find they have the pleasant property that $s^2 = t^2 -1$ and that they generate $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in a very simple way (as a free $F[t]$ module of rank 2). This makes it natural to see if everything one needed to express in the language of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in the first undecidability result can be recast in the language of $F[t]$.

Comment: Why do the elements $t$ and $s$ generate $F[u, u^{-1}]$ ? $$$$ At which point of the proof do we use the Lemma? $$$$ I still don't understand the part: "So, we see that the positive existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is interpretable in $F[t]$ with only one problem: we do not have constants for $u$ and $u^{-1}$ but only for $\frac{u+u^{-1}}{2}=t$. 

So, the positive existential theory of $F[t]$ is undecidable provided that the theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable in the language $\{0, 1, u+u^{-1}/2, +, \cdot\}$." Could you explain it to me?

Comment: We want to map the elements of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ into the elements of $F[t]$, right? 

There is no mapping of the elements $u=t+\sqrt{t^2-1}$ and $u^{-1}=t-\sqrt{t^2-1}$ into an element of $F[t]$, because the square root is not contained at the language so $t+\sqrt{t^2-1}$ and $t-\sqrt{t^2-1}$ are not elements of $F[t]$. 

Have I understood it correct so far? 

Why do we have to look then at the language $\{0, 1, u+u^{-1}/2, +, \cdot\}$ and not at the original language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ ? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: But the base is $\{1, \sqrt{t^2-1}\}$, so isn't the representation of $u$, $(t, 1) \in F[t]$ and the representation of $u^{-1}$, $(t, -1) \in F[t]$ ? So there is a mapping from $u$ and $u^{-1}$ into an element of $F[t]$. Or is this wrong? I got stuck right now...

Comment: We want to map statements about $F[u, u^{-1}]$ into equivalent statements about $F[t]$. The way this is done is by showing that $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be viewed as a free $F[t]$-module of rank $2$. This is like mapping statements about complex numbers into equivalent statements about *pairs* of real numbers.

Comment: What does the expression "free $F[t]$-module of rank $2$" mean? $$$$ So, $F[u, u^{-1}]$ represents the complex numbers and $F[t]$ represents the pairs of real numbers? Or have I understood wrong your last sentence?

Comment: Mary: no, in my analogy $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is analogous to $\mathbb{C}$ and $F[t]$ is analogous to $\mathbb{R}$. In the language of $\mathbb{C}$ you can make the (true) statement that every number is a square: $\forall z \exists w\cdot w^2 = z$. This translates into the following statement about real numbers $\forall x \forall y\exists u \exists v \cdot (x = u^2 - v^2 \land y = 2uv)$.

Comment: Oh, I see... But why do we have to look at the language $\{0, 1, u+u^{-1}/2, +, \cdot \}$ and not at the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ ?

Comment: What the paper is doing is translating a statement from the language with $u$ and $u^{-1}$ into the language with just $t$, so that an undecidable sentence in the former language gives an undecidable sentence in the latter.

Comment: I think I understood it now...

Comment: I have also a question about the last part: $$$$ "$F[u, u^{-1}]$ is generated over $F$ as a ring by $t$ and $v$, hence any equation in $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written as $p(t, v) = 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$, but $v^2 = t^2-1$, so we can arrange for $p$ to have the form $vf(t) - g(t)$ for $f, g \in F[t]$. and then $p(r, t) = 0$ is equivalent to $fv = g$." $$$$ Why, when we know that $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is generated over $F$ by $t$ and $v$, we conclude that any equation in $F[u, u^{-1}]$ can be written as $p(t, v) = 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$ ?

Comment: The equation will have the form $a = b$ where $a$ and $b$ can be written as polynomials in $t$ and $v$, say $a = q(t, v)$ and $b = r(t, v)$ and then $a = b$ is equivalent to $a - b = 0$ which is equivalent to $p(t, v) = 0$ where $p(t, v)$ is the polynomial $q(t, v) = r(t,v)$.

Comment: I see... And why can we arrange for $p$ to have the form $vf(t) - g(t)$ for $f, g \in F[t]$ when we have that $v^2 = t^2-1$ ?

Comment: Because the equation $v^2 = t^2 - 1$ allows us to replace higher power of $v$ by terms of lower degree in $v$. [As an aside: what is your interest in this paper by Phaedas?]

Comment: I haven't really understood it... Could you explain it further to me? $$$$ I chose for my master thesis the topic of undecidable and decidable problems that are related to differntial equations and the prof gave me this paper to read...

Comment: Do you mean for example the following? $v^5+t=v(v^2)^2+t=v(t^2-1)^2+t$

Comment: But how do we conclude, when we write the equations in that form, that $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable also in the language $\{0, 1, u+u^{-1}/2, +, \cdot \}$ ?

Comment: I read it again and that's what I understood: 

The mapping of the reduction is $u \mapsto u-t =:v$. 

We write all the equations in the form $fv=g$ where $f,g \in F[t]$ and when we square these equations we get $f^2v^2=g^2 \Rightarrow f^2(t^2-1)=g^2$, so all the equations are in $F[t]$, where $t=(u+u^{-1})/2$. 

Is this correct?

Comment: @MaryStar: I think you are on roughly the right lines now.

Comment: I added at my initial post how I understand the whole proof of Theorem $3$... Could you take a look at EDIT$5$ and tell me if it is correct?

Comment: What does it mean that "$F[u,u^{−1}]$ is a module over $F[t]$" ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics) for the definition of a module over a ring (or, and much better, read an introductory book on ring theory or attend a course). Whenever $R$ is a subring of a ring $S$, $S$ automatically becomes a module over $R$ in a standard way. Here $F[t]$ is a subring of $F[u, u^{-1}]$.

Comment: Could you clarify to me at which point of the proof we use the Lemma?

Comment: I have read the proof several times but I still haven't understood where the Lemma helps us... Do you have an idea?