# The diophantine problem for $R[T]$ is solvable iff the diophantine problem for $R$ is solvable

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, computability

One part of the paper that I am reading is the following:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $R'$ be a subring of $R$.

We say that the diophantine problem for $R$ with coefficients in $R'$ is unsolvable (solvable) if there exists no (an) algorithm to decide whether or not a polynomial equation (in several variables) with coefficients in $R'$ has a solution in $R$.

$$\dots \dots \dots \dots \dots$$

Theorem.

Let $R$ be an integral domain of characteristic zero; then the diophantine problem for $R[T]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ is unsolvable.

($R[T]$ denotes the ring of polynomials over $R$, in one variable $T$.)

$$\dots \dots \dots \dots \dots$$

> It is obvious that the diophantine problem for $R[T]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is solvable if and only if the diophantine problem for $R$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is solvable.

$$$$

Could you explain to me the last sentence?

Why does this stand?

Does the direction $\Leftarrow$ stand because of the following?

We know that there is an algorithm that decides whether or not an equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution in $R$.

We consider this equation as the constant term of a polynomial equation, so there is an algorithm that decides whether or not an equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution in $R[T]$.

Is the justification of this direction correct?

Comment: And why should there be one variable? Can lead as an example, at least one algorithm?

Comment: It is from the paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-242-00/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7.pdf at the second page (392). @individ

Comment: So they prove theorems.  These fantasies to the solution of Diophantine equations and for finding the desired polynomial generally has no relation.     In practice we often need to solve the inverse problem.  The solvability of the equation depends not only on the coefficients and the unknown number and its type. That is how they are connected to each other and what relationship.  For a particular equation is a formula of the solution not affected by any factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial equation 
$$P(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0,\tag{1}$$ 
where $P$ has integer coefficients, has a solution in $R[T]$ if and only if it has a solution in $R$.

For one direction, note that any solution of (1) in $R$ is in particular a solution in $R[T]$.

For the other direction, suppose that the ordered $n$-tuple $(Q_1(T), \dots, Q_n(T))$ of polynomials is a solution of (1) in $R[T]$. Then the ordered $n$-tuple $(Q_1(0),\dots,Q_n(0))$ is a solution of (1) in $R$.

Thus any algorithm for determining solvability in one of the rings $R$ or $R[T]$ automatically determines solvability in the other.

Comment: At the part when we suppose that the ordered $n$-tuple $(Q_1(T), \dots, Q_n(T))$ of polynomials is a solution of (1) in $R[T]$ and we say that the ordered $n$-tuple $(Q_1(0),\dots,Q_n(0))$ is a solution of (1) in $R$, could we have taken any ordered $n$-tuple $(Q_1(x),\dots,Q_n(x))$ where $x\in R$ instead of $(Q_1(0),\dots,Q_n(0))$ ? Or is there a specific reason to take $T=0$ ?

Comment: I chose $0$ for simplicity. For our purposes we can use any $x\in R$ to evaluate at.

Comment: I see... Thanks for the explanation!! :-) 
$$$$ 
I have also an other question... In the paper that I am reading there appears often the term "elementary theory". Is this the same as "existential theory" ?

Comment: Not the same at all, unless language is being used in a weird way. The elementary theory of groups, the elementary theory of fields, the elementary theory of real-closed fields, the elementary theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$, and so on have well-established technical meanings that have no connection with existential theory.

Comment: The existential theory of the ring $R$ in $L$ is decidable if there is an algorithm which, given any existential sentence (a sentence that is of the form: existential quantifiers in front, no logical connecties other than $\land$, $\lor$, negation and implication inside) of $L$, decides whether or not that is true or false in $R$, right? What does it mean that the elementary theory is decidable or undecidable?

Comment: It means that there is an algorithm that, given **any** sentence  $\varphi$ of the language, determines whether or not that sentence is a theorem. It is for example known that there is no algorithm for determining whether a sentence over the usual language is true in the rationals. But it is **NOT** known whether or not there is an algorithm which, given any *existential* sentence $\varphi$, will determine whether or not $\varphi$ is true in the rationals.

Comment: About substituting any element of $R$, I take it back. We can substitute any element of $\mathbb{Z}$. But if we substitute an arbitrary element of $R$, we may no longer have a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. It is true that the equation has a solution in $R$, but the supposed algorithm is only guaranteed to work for polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: Ok... I see... 
$$$$ 
I have also an other question... Do you maybe know at which paper of Denef there is a proof of theorems like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375844/the-existential-theory-is-undecidable/1376256?noredirect=1#comment2812553_1376256 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380768/algorithm-to-answer-existential-questions-reduction ?

Comment: My memory is not accurate here, but the results you are referring to are not Denef at all, they are Pheidas (my spelling may be off).

Comment: Yes, I found these theorems at a paper of Pheidas. I have heard that Denef proves also these theorems but I don't know exactly at which paper...

Comment: I don't recall seeing the $R(t,t^{-1})$ in any paper by Denef,  and probably have no great advantage over you in searching.  It might be mentioned in Poonen's survey.

Comment: Do you maybe mean this paper of Poonen: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/sampler.pdf ?

Comment: This is a very good survey. I think there is also a more Hilbert's 10th focused survey, but maybe I am recalling a talk.